# EditText only default value showing

Tags: android

I have a piece of code, where in an AlertDialog I want from that dialog's EditText text to be placed in a string. My only problem, that the string only get's the default value of the EditText that is defined in the layout even in I edit the value in AVD.

Here is the code:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(YanonymousActivity.this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.addnode, null));
    builder.setCancelable(true);
   // mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.add_node_text);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Add node", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   setContentView(R.layout.addnode);
                    mNodeName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.add_node);
                    mNodeColor = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.add_node_color);
                    addNodeName = mNodeName.getText().toString();   
                    addNodeColor = Integer.parseInt(mNodeColor.getText().toString(), 16);
                    if(mNodeName.getText().toString() == null || mNodeColor.getText().toString() == null) {
                        showtoast("No node name/color");
                    }
                    else {
                        final String actual_theme = YourWorldView.getTheme();
                        //final int value = Integer.parseInt(addNodeColor, 16);  
                        for (YanoTheme t : YourWorldView.YanoThemes) {
                            if (t.getThemeName() == actual_theme) {
                                toastmessage = addNodeName + "\n" + addNodeColor;
                                showtoast("We did it, reddit");
                                YourWorldView.YanoThemes.get(0).addItem(addNodeName,addNodeColor);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: not clear what youre asking

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. You've to get the view of the Dialog. For getting the text from `EditText` which is in the custom layout of your dialog, do this inside onClick listener of the positive button:

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

    Dialog d = (Dialog) dialog;
    EditText mNodeName = (EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.add_node);
    String text = mNodeName.getText().toString();
    //...
}
```

Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

if what i understand is correct then your issue is that you checking if the editText is null or empty which regarding to what you mentioned is that it has default value which will always make this statement will always be false`if(mNodeName.getText().toString() == null || mNodeColor.getText().toString() == null)`
because you said that the `editText` has a default value.